# Save the inserted count of IDs into a variable - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am inserting some values into a table while saving the count of rows inserted in a variable like this,

```
declare @tempinsertcount int
set @tempinsertcount = 0

insert into  #tempTable (Time, terminal_id, claims)
    select 
        Time, terminal_id, claims
    from 
        Claims as c   
    join 
        (select 
             min(Time) as mintime, dateadd(mi,-60,min(Time) as hrprior, terminal_id
         from 
             #tempTable
         group by 
             terminal_id) as temp on c.terminal_id = temp.terminal_id 
                                  and c.[Time] > temp.hrprior

set @tempinsertcount = @tempinsertcount+ @@ROWCOUNT
```

My inserted values (output) will be like this,

```
Time                           terminal_id     claims     
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-04-19 23:59:00                  8           147           
2017-04-19 23:59:00                  9            87            
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 10           284           
2017-04-20 00:00:00                  8           148           
2017-04-20 00:00:00                  9            88            
2017-04-20 00:00:00                 10           285          
2017-04-20 00:01:00                  8           149           
2017-04-20 00:01:00                  9            89
2017-04-20 00:01:00                 10           286
```

Above, there are 9 rows that gets inserted. I get  9 for `select @tempinsertcount` and works fine.

However, when I try to save the count of `terminal_id` in a variable, which will be 3 ids (one of each). I tried the following (my whole query),

```
declare @tempinsertcount int
set @tempinsertcount = 0

declare @termidcount nvarchar
set @termidcount = 0


insert into  #tempTable (Time, terminal_id, claims)

select Time, terminal_id, claims
        from Claims as c   
        join (
            select min(Time) as mintime, dateadd(mi,-60,min(Time) as hrprior, terminal_id
            from #tempTable
            group by terminal_id
            ) as temp
            on c.terminal_id = temp.terminal_id and c.[Time] > temp.hrprior
set @tempinsertcount = @tempinsertcount + @@ROWCOUNT

set @termidcount = (select count(terminal_id) --, terminal_id
            from #tempTable
            group by terminal_id
)
select @termidcount
select @tempinsertcount
```

Here, I am getting an error for `@termidcount` variable,

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I know, based on my query I am trying to save more than one value in the variable. How can I instantiate `@termidcount` variable get ID counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily as follows

**Explanation**

You can get both the total number of rows and the distinct terminal_id count in one query by using count distinct

Query

```
select count(*), count(distinct terminal_id)
from #tempTable
```

Here a working [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bffa7/3)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should change your sql code

```
set @termidcount = (select count(terminal_id) --, terminal_id
            from # tempTable
            group by terminal_id
)
```

to

```
   set @termidcount = (select COUNT (DISTINCT terminal_id) from #tempTable)
```